# Sending warning message from listener file laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I am checking the condition for verified email or not and, if not, then redirecting the user to the login with an error message but in my `login.blade`. I cant show it please find the following code:

**Loginauthenticated.php**

```
public function handle(Authenticated $event)
    {
        if ( $event->user->verified_email==0 )
        {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', ['your message,here']); 
        }
    }
```

**login.blade.php**

```
@if (\Session::has('success'))
   <div class="alert alert-success">
        <ul>
            <li>{!! \Session::get('success') !!}</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Are you saying that your login.blade.php file is not seeing the "success" session variable?

Comment: yes ,in short how can i show th warring message sent from the listener file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in Laravel-5.2. Hope this will solve your problem.

 In my controller

```
 return redirect()->back()->with(['success'=>'your message,here']);
```

In my blade

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 success">
        {{Session::get('success')}} 
  </div>
 </div>
@endif
```

Comment: No luck ,I am redirect from the listener not from controller so may be that's   the reason.

Comment: this works for sure.so if you are still have problems, you better to move controller method.